# Virtual Desktops on Windows working like MacOS

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-desktop

Long time Mac user that's used macos virtual desktops for forever. Started a new job & they gave me a PC, so I'm working with Windows and have found that virtual desktops on Windows don't work the same as on macos.

In macos, I can assign mail to desktop 1, a browser to desktop 2, music to desktop 3, etc. And when I click on the icon in my dock, it takes me to that application running on the appropriate virtual desktop.  But when I attempt to do this in Windows, it just starts another instance of the application - thus defeating the purpose of multiple desktops.

Is there a way to make Windows virtual desktops work like macos in that it doesn't start a new instance of the application, but rather takes you to the existing running version on another desktop?

Answer (score 1):

You may use
[VDesk](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk)
to launch a programs on a given virtual desktop.

The run command looks like:

```
    vdesk 2 command
```

You may add icons to the taskbar (it's not called dock) that launch the
application to the right virtual desktop.